# Matlab jsonencode not encoding all of the structure

Tags: json, matlab

I need to generate a JSON file from a Matlab structure, which is quite big.

Using this code produce the desired json, with the correct structure:

```matlab
fid=fopen(strcat(date, '_', 'EV.json'),'w');
fprintf(fid, jsonencode(S));
```

But when I open the generated JSON, I notice that a big part of it is missing, it only encoded the first part of all my data. Does anybody know what could this be caused by? I was thinking that maybe a memory allocation problem.

If I do:

```matlab
encodedJSON = jsonencode(S);
encodedJSON(end)
```

it returns '}', meaning the last character of the variable encodedJSON is a closing bracket, but when I open the file I generated, it ends abruptly in the middle of my data like on this picture, which shows the very last part of my generated json file:
[image: The very last part of my generated json file]

It also weighs 68KB while other smaller JSONS generated with the same code weigh almost twice.

Comment: What does your data look like? Maybe the missing part is an object that `jasonencode` doesn’t know what to do with?

Comment: It's a structure made up of other 8 structures, each of them with one or two tables inside. It's weird, cause it works without a problem at the beginning, but it looks like a part of the JSON is missing. I edited my question to add more information.

Comment: Are you closing your file? `fclose(fid)`. I’m guessing some of the stuff is in the write buffer and not yet committed to file.

Comment: So silly, that was it... Thanks a lot!

Comment: Oh, and you also should write to file with `fprintf(fid, '%s', jsonencode(S))`, to prevent the string being interpreted as a format string. In the format string some characters like `\\ ` and `%` are treated specially.

Comment: I like to do an `RAII.myfile = onCleanup(@() fclose(fid));` immediately after my `fopen()` calls so the file handle always gets flushed and closed regardless of why the function execution terminates: onCleanup (and `handle` destructors) will always execute, even if you exit the function due to an error or even a `dbquit`.